# Short story from almost 50 years ago

Tags: story-identification

Short Sci-Fi story published early to mid 1970s. A planet with primitive indigenous people is being conquered by a high tech empire. The skies are full of smart drones. Technology wins. [Thought this was both prescient and counter-politically correct for the times after a high-tech United States could not prevail in South East Asia.] Story? Author? Date?

I read this in an American magazine; English language. The primitive people were humanoid; I can't recall if this took place on Earth in the future or on an Earth-like planet.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Did you read it in English? In a magazine or anthology? Do you remember other stories from the same publication? What the cover looked like? Also, was there a protagonist, and if so, from which side of the conflict? Was the high-tech empire or the primitive people non-human? Any detail could help.

Comment: Is it told from the viewpoint of the invaders or the natives?

Comment: Did the drones drop food and supplies?